Identify duplicate entries in SQL*Plus
I have a database where values are held with a unique ID and a sequence number to order the data. For some IDs sequence number has been duplicated, here is an example where ID 0001 has the error and 0002 is OK:



ID
seqno
other_data
date_inserted




0001
1
XXXXXXXXXX
14/01/2023


0001
2
XXXXYXXXXX
17/02/2023


0001
2
XXXYXXXXXX
16/12/2023


0001
3
YXXXXXXXXX
22/12/2023


0001
4
YXXXXYXXXX
22/12/2023


0002
1
XXXXXXXYYX
01/04/2023


0002
2
XXXXYXXXXY
08/02/2024


0002
3
XXXXXXXXYY
07/07/2024


0002
4
YYYXXXXXXX
02/08/2024



There are thousands of IDs - HOW do I report out the IDs affected and the seqno that've been duplicated.
BONUS: How can I rectify this issue and realign the seqnos for affected IDs. As you can see the 'date' field isn't unique (i.e. a single date can have multiple seqnos).
Thanks in advance!

To your Bonus second question: How would you do it if you have to fix seqno manually? You explain how, and we can help with the code.

GROUP BY, select id,sqno from table group by id,sqno having count(*)>2 and ROW_NUMBER() may help with the bonus

I don't think you mean SQL*Plus, which is a command-line interface that doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.

"I have a database where values are held with a unique ID" - No, the ID is not unique (and hence a bad column name). What is supposed to be unique is the combination of id + seqno, but you obviously forgot to implement a unique constraint on that tuple in your table. As to your bonus question: Is it possible for an ID to have two seqnos in the same day? If not, then just drop the seqno, as it would only contain redundant information. If you can have two seqnos in the same day for the same ID, then you may already have run into a situation where you can only guess which is first.

If you want to re-generate the seqno values then use the ROW_NUMBER analytic function and a MERGE statement (correlating on the ROWID pseudo-column):
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_inserted, seqno) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET seqno   =  rn
  WHERE seqno != rn;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, seqno, other_data, date_inserted) AS
SELECT '0001', 1, 'XXXXXXXXXX', DATE '2023-01-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001', 2, 'XXXXYXXXXX', DATE '2023-02-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001', 2, 'XXXYXXXXXX', DATE '2023-12-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001', 3, 'YXXXXXXXXX', DATE '2023-12-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001', 4, 'YXXXXYXXXX', DATE '2023-12-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', 1, 'XXXXXXXYYX', DATE '2023-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', 2, 'XXXXYXXXXY', DATE '2024-02-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', 3, 'XXXXXXXXYY', DATE '2024-07-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', 4, 'YYYXXXXXXX', DATE '2024-08-02' FROM DUAL;

Then after the MERGE the table contains:



ID
SEQNO
OTHER_DATA
DATE_INSERTED




0001
1
XXXXXXXXXX
2023-01-14 00:00:00


0001
2
XXXXYXXXXX
2023-02-17 00:00:00


0001
3
XXXYXXXXXX
2023-12-16 00:00:00


0001
4
YXXXXXXXXX
2023-12-22 00:00:00


0001
5
YXXXXYXXXX
2023-12-22 00:00:00


0002
1
XXXXXXXYYX
2023-04-01 00:00:00


0002
2
XXXXYXXXXY
2024-02-08 00:00:00


0002
3
XXXXXXXXYY
2024-07-07 00:00:00


0002
4
YYYXXXXXXX
2024-08-02 00:00:00




If you just want to know the affected rows then:
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_inserted, seqno)
           AS new_seqno
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  seqno != new_seqno

Which outputs:



ID
SEQNO
OTHER_DATA
DATE_INSERTED
NEW_SEQNO




0001
2
XXXYXXXXXX
2023-12-16 00:00:00
3


0001
3
YXXXXXXXXX
2023-12-22 00:00:00
4


0001
4
YXXXXYXXXX
2023-12-22 00:00:00
5



fiddle
